# JS Error in Webpack production mode but not in development mode - Help me find the cause

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am a frontend developer (recently made the transition from backend dev to frontend dev) and I inherited our Javascript codebase from my predecessor and I am trying to maintain and optimize it.

We have the problem that the Javascript code behaves differently in production and in development environment. There are errors that only occur in production and I don't know where the discrepancy in the behavior comes from. Our goal is to have the same behavior and more importantly errors in both development and production environment, so when the code goes live (production environment), we can be sure there will be no unexpected errors.

Our build process works with Webpack (webpack@4.17.1), also we use babel (@babel/core@7.0.0) to transpile our Javascript code.

I did some research to find out where the differences come from. The one thing I came up with was the [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), but as far as I understand it the strict mode gets also used in development environment, so this is probably no the cause.

Here is a simple example of this behavior.
We have a js file called utilities.js, which is just a collection of helpful methods:

```
/**
 * @param {String} url
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
export function loadScript(url) {
    let loaded = this.getData('scriptsLoaded', []);
    ...
}


/**
 * @param {String} key
 * @param {*} [type={}]
 * @returns {*}
 */
export function getData(key, type = {}) {
    window.auskunft = window.auskunft || {};
    return window.auskunft[key] = window.auskunft[key] || type;
}
```

Now loadScript() gets called somewhere else and because we are not in a class context (my guess is it was refactored from class to collection of independent methods), getData() cannot be called with "this".

This leads to an error in production environment (which affects/stops the rest of the js code), but in development this error doesn't occur and everything works fine. I would expect to get the error in both development and production environment.

This is the production error:

> utilities.js:68 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getData is not a
>   function at Object.p (utilities.js:68) at Function.value
>   (client.js:163) at t.value (app.js:27) at main.js:14

So if anyone has some clues what could cause this discrepancy and where to look to fix this behavior, that would be awesome!

Comment: Production don't install dev requirements unless you use some plugins. Where is your webpack configuration and package.json?

Comment: The very first thing I'd do is add a `console.log(this)` to find out what `this` actually points to.